# Chrome 67 при старте через Codeception не отображает текст элементов

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, codeception

Запускаю Chrome при прогоне тестов Codeception
Получаю браузер, в котором нет текста элементов
Началось это после обновления браузера до версии 67.0.3396.87
Новые cromedriver (2.40) и selenium_server (3.12) не решают проблему

[image: Не отображается текст элементов Chrome]

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка 67 версии, помогло обновление до 68 версии (пока бета)